# Deradicalization of denominators

Tags: fractions, radicals

Task: Develop a fraction equivalent to
$$
1\over{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}c_in^{i/n}}
$$
in which the denominator is rational.

Comment: If you're trying to do what I think yoiu're trying to do, the way to do it is to post the question, and to post the answer as an answer.

Comment: Mr. @Gerry Myerson: I have to high-tail it back to the sandbox: Somehow, even though I posted my answer, it sems to have gotten kiboshed. Back in a minute.

Comment: Mr. @Gerry Myerson: Thank you for your advice. By the way, I admire your constant attitude of helpfulness; it's greatly appreciated. All respect, Donn S. Miller

Comment: Can the people voting to close perhaps say why? This question seems okay to me - the OP is answering the question themself, so there is no issue with it being homework or similar!

Comment: I proposed a task, then I posited a method for accomplishing the task. Please tell me that this has not been criticized simply because, as in the Jeopardy quiz show, I did not frame it in the form of a question.

Comment: @user1729PhD This just came up in the review queue (just the question). My immediate reaction was to close because I can't understand question due to the terminology *equivalent fraction*, then I noticed the comments and opened the question to see the answer. I saw *equivalent* is supposed to mean equal and I chose to keep it closed. The question is not clear to me. Whether I was ignorant in my decision is of no concern here, I'm merely pointing out why I kept it closed and why I could close it if I saw it before it was closed.

Comment: So it boils down to my choice of the word "equivalent," as opposed to the practically synonymous "equal?" Oh, please ...

Comment: @GitGud I disagree with your pedantry, because I think it might actually be incorrect pedantry. If my memory serves me correctly, $\frac12$ and $\frac24$ are *equivalent* rather than equal, in the same way that $1$ and $13$ are equivalent modulo $12$ rather than equal. This interpretation is backed up by a [superficial google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=equivalent+fractions&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gfe_rd=cr&ei=fnuhU_CSMqLY8gegm4DYDA&gws_rd=ssl).

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi Synonymous? I don't think so. Statements are equivalent, mathematical objects are equal (or different, if they are not equal), not equivalent. I honestly couldn't understand your question. Only by coming here and seeing the answer did I understand it. Once I gained this information, I understood the question and you could have opted to open it. But I chose not to because I really think it's not clear.

Comment: (But words are not my thing so I may be entirely incorrect. If I am then I still disagree with your pedantry because it is precisely that - pedantry!)

Comment: @user1729PhD "Whether I was ignorant in my decision is of no concern here". And I meant to imply that maybe I'm being ignorant here. Maybe it's widely used. But I must say, it's very bad terminology. And again: I really couldn't understand the question. I've often been described as pedantic. I take it as a compliment. I don't see pedantry as a bad thing, quite the contrary. Why wouldn't one want to be as clear as possible, I do not understand.

Comment: Hey, man, look! I wasn't asking anything; I was sharing. Close it, open it, blow it up -- I really don't care. Goodbye!

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi Don't take it personally. At least on my part this isn't a fight at all. We're just communicating. For what it's worth, I think your question will eventually be reopened and I'm glad it will. I just couldn't bring myself to do it.

Comment: @GitGud I don't see how you could not understand the question. I mean, it has a whiff of poor English about it but it is unfair to hold that against the OP. They are just doing something like $\frac1{\sqrt2}=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$ in an odd setting...Anyway, I think we have picked this apart enough and I need my lunch! (and I apologise for jumping on you like this when all you did was take the time to explain why you didn't re-open the question. So thanks for explaining.)

Comment: @user1729 PhD: I couldn't let this go without thanking you. I followed the "superficial Google search" to which you alluded; and to my mind you achieved Game, Set, Match and Championship! I hope I die before I develop such a chromosomal-level inability to admit to being wrong as I have seen in other parts of this kerfluffle. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Develop the denominator. The objective will be a fraction in which the numerator and denominator are two nearly-similar determinants which differ only in their top rows. The initial form of the denominator is

$\begin{vmatrix}
c_0&c_{n-1}n&c_{n-2}n&\cdots&c_3n&c_2n&c_1n\\
c_1&c_0&c_{n-1}n&\cdots&c_4n&c_3n&c_2n\\
c_2&c_1&c_0&\cdots&c_5n&c_4n&c_3n\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
c_{n-3}&c_{n-4}&c_{n-5}&\cdots&c_0&c_{n-1}n&c_{n-2}n\\
c_{n-2}&c_{n-3}&c_{n-4}&\cdots&c_1&c_0&c_{n-1}n\\
c_{n-1}&c_{n-2}&c_{n-3}&\cdots&c_2&c_1&c_0\\
\end{vmatrix}$.

Step 2: The numerator is merely the same determinant as the denominator, except that its top row is replaced by

$\begin{matrix}
1&\sqrt[n]n&\sqrt[n]{n^2}&\cdots&\sqrt[n]{n^{n-3}}&\sqrt[n]{n^{n-2}}&\sqrt[n]{n^{n-1}}\\
\end{matrix}$.

This gives rise, for example, to the following:

${1\over{A+B\sqrt n}}=
{{\begin{vmatrix}
1&\sqrt n\\
B&A\\
\end{vmatrix}}\over
{\begin{vmatrix}
A&Bn\\
B&A\\
\end{vmatrix}}}={{A-B\sqrt n}\over{A^2-B^2 n}}$ and
${1\over{A+B\sqrt[3] n+C\sqrt[3]{n^2}}}=
{{\begin{vmatrix}
1&\sqrt[3]n&\sqrt[3]{n^2}\\
B&A&Cn\\
C&B&A\\
\end{vmatrix}}\over{
\begin{vmatrix}
A&Cn&Bn\\
B&A&Cn\\
C&B&A\\
\end{vmatrix}}}={{A^2-BCn+(C^2n-AB)\sqrt[3]n+(B^2-AC)\sqrt[3]{n^2}}\over{A^3+B^3 n+C^3 n^2-3ABCn}}$.

An example of how a typical denominator (between the bars) is set up:

$\begin{array}{ccccc|cccccc|ccccc}
F&E&D&C&B&A&Fn&En&Dn&Cn&Bn&&&&&\\
&F&E&D&C&B&A&Fn&En&Dn&Cn&Bn&&&&\\
&&F&E&D&C&B&A&Fn&En&Dn&Cn&Bn&&&\\
&&&F&E&D&C&B&A&Fn&En&Dn&Cn&Bn&&\\
&&&&F&E&D&C&B&A&Fn&En&Dn&Cn&Bn&\\
&&&&&F&E&D&C&B&A&Fn&En&Dn&Cn&Bn\\
\end{array}$

Comment: I think I understood the Question, but the Answer needs more explanation for me to follow.